# How to pass javascript variable to java scriplet in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, variables, scriptlet

I have to pass this processID in my java scriplet so that i can query database based on particular ID.
`processID` is coming from onchange function of dropdown.
But I am not able to do that.

```
<script>
function load_division(processID){

    var id = processID.toString();

    <% String connectionUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@PRA:1540:";
        String dbName = "System";
        String userId = "Prakhar";
        String password = "PS#5QW8";
        %> 
    <% String i%>= id; //giving Error
        PreparedStatement statement2 = null;
        ResultSet divSet = null;
    try {
        Connection connection1 = DriverManager.getConnection(
            connectionUrl + dbName, 
            userId, 
            password
        );
        statement2 = connection1.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT distinct ID, " + 
            "Name FROM process_group " + 
            "WHERE ID =" + i + 
            " ORDER BY name"
        );
        divSet = statement2.executeQuery();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }%>

    var x = document.getElementById("division");
    var option = document.createElement("option"); 
    var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    <% while (divSet.next()) {

        divSet.getInt("ID");%>
        docfrag.appendChild(new Option(
            "<%=divSet.getString("Name")%>",
            "<%=divSet.getInt("ID")%>"
        ));

        x.appendChild(docfrag);
    <%}%>    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make a server call directly. You need to make a server request.

javascript plays on client side and JSP plays on server side.

What you need is you have to make a server request. And send that string as a query parameter.

Two options to achieve this.

1. HTML forms

   Sample.html

   ## Please tell me about yourself

   ```
   <form action="SimpleFormHandler.jsp" method="get">

   Name: <input type="text" name="firstName">
     <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
   Sex:
     <input type="radio" checked name="sex" value="male">Male
     <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
   <p>
   What Java primitive type best describes your personality:
   <select name="javaType">
     <option value="boolean">boolean</option> 
     <option value="byte">byte</option> 
     <option value="char" selected>char</option> 
     <option value="double">double</option> 
     <option value="float">float</option> 
     <option value="int">int</option> 
     <option value="long">long</option> 
   </select>
   <br>
   <input type="submit">
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

SampleFormHandler.jsp

```
<html>
<body>

<%

// Grab the variables from the form.
  String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
  String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
  String sex = request.getParameter("sex");
  String javaType = request.getParameter("javaType");
%>
<%-- Print out the variables. --%>
<h1>Hello, <%=firstName%> <%=lastName%>!</h1>
I see that you are <%=sex%>. You know, you remind me of a
<%=javaType%> variable I once knew.

</body>
</html>
```

2. Ajax.

Send the data using post and put the results in a div

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/YourServlet",
  type: "post",
  data: values,
  success: function(){
      alert("success");
       $("#result").html('submitted successfully');
  },
  error:function(){
      alert("failure");
      $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
  }   
});
```

Do not confuse that JSP and java script existed on same document(or file). Yes but JSP part compiles on server side and JavaScript executes by browser.

Comment: +1 for this. One thing I tell developers is that your Javascript (and HTML for that matter) is the OUTPUT of any Java code - including scriptlets in a JSP. Not only is Java running on the server side, the Java code also runs before the Javascript is rendered and executed in your browser.